# сохранение в текстовый файл

Tags: python

Сохраняю данные в файл. Вот кусок кода:

```
def wifi_connect(ssid, psk):
  f.write('    ssid="' + str(ssid) + '"\n')
  f.write('    psk="' + str(psk) + '"\n')
  f.write('}\n')
  f.close()
```

В итоге файл выглядит так:

```
ssid="b'value1'"

psk="b'value2'"
```

А мне нужно:

```
ssid="value1"

psk="value2"
```

Как это можно сделать и в чем мой косяк?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это байтовая строка, её необходимо декодировать:

```
f.write('    ssid="' + ssid.decode("utf-8") + '"\n')
f.write('    psk="' + psk.decode("utf-8") + '"\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно декодировать байты в текст.

```py
def wifi_connect(ssid, psk):
    f.write('    ssid="' + ssid.decode('utf-8') + '"\n')
    f.write('    psk="' + psk.decode('utf-8') + '"\n')
    f.write('}\n')
    f.close()
```